# Move Triangle Arrow Sideways

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main menu on the header with links, and i have a triangle that moves as the user hovers from one page to another. I want to keep it moving, but i would like to see the transition showing like on this website: harris-active.co.uk

CSS Code:

```
/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#nav-wrap .container {
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border:none;
}

#nav-wrap table {
width:100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
padding:0px;
}

#nav-wrap table td {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul {
list-style: none;
float: right;
margin-right:40px;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin-left:40px;
position:relative;
top:0px;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li a {
display: block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color: #999999;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 50px 0px;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 16px;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li#active a,
#nav-wrap .container ul li a:hover {
color: #fff;
border: 0;
text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
background: url(nav-hover.png) no-repeat center bottom;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

this is how it is currently showing on my live site: tradey-lb.com

Comment: Check out [this LavaLamp Plugin](http://nixbox.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/demos/original.html) for jQuery

Comment: that is not what i want Miro, check out my site

Comment: this is not a website where you just request something and it magically gets done for you. You can adapt the plugin to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

With an html as this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="m1">menu1</li>
  <li class="m2">menu2</li>
  <li class="m3">menu3</li>
  <li class="m4">menu4</li>
  <li id="arrowid" class="arrow"></li>
</ul>
```

You could use absolute position to place the triangle whatever position like:

```
.arrow {  
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:85px;
}
```

Then add some classes for each different hover like:

```
.position1 {
  left:85px;
}
.position2 {
  left:195px;
}
.position3 {
  left:300px;
}
```

And with a easy function, when you hover on your menu you remove any class already there on "Arrow" and then add the position class needed... like:

```
 $(".m1").hover(function () {
        $('#arrowid').attr('class', 'arrow');
    $('#arrowid').addClass("position1");
 });
 $(".m2").hover(function () {
        $('#arrowid').attr('class', 'arrow');
    $('#arrowid').addClass("position2");
 });
```

Full example:

```js
 $(".m1").hover(function () {
   $('#arrowid').attr('class', 'arrow');
    $('#arrowid').addClass("position1");
 });
 $(".m2").hover(function () {
   $('#arrowid').attr('class', 'arrow');
    $('#arrowid').addClass("position2");
 });
  $(".m3").hover(function () {
   $('#arrowid').attr('class', 'arrow');
    $('#arrowid').addClass("position3");
 });
  $(".m4").hover(function () {
   $('#arrowid').attr('class', 'arrow');
    $('#arrowid').addClass("position4");
 });
```

```css
ul {position:relative; border-bottom:2px solid #000;}
li {display:inline-block;padding:12px 30px;overflow:visible;}
.arrow {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;  
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:85px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.position1 {
  left:85px;
}
.position2 {
  left:195px;
}
.position3 {
  left:300px;
}
.position4 {
  left:410px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="m1">menu1</li>
  <li class="m2">menu2</li>
  <li class="m3">menu3</li>
  <li class="m4">menu4</li>
  <li id="arrowid" class="arrow"></li>
</ul>
```

I was tempted to delete my answer once I saw your rude comment to another user but this may help someone else around so I'll keep it for now. But try ro learn some manners.

Comment: but how do you put that code with my corresponding css?

Comment: You have to work it yourself. We are here to help if possible but not to make your web. with your current css you will never be able to do this effect so you have to change it. The html base is the same, a html list.

Comment: you have many triangles images... one on each link (that shows on hover) while you need just one element moving from side to side,

Comment: hello @Alvaro. I appreciate your answer but i guess i'm looking in the wrong place. I actually needed someone to fix my code entirely. I'm not asking for a lesson on how to create such an effect from scratch. Anyways, hope your answer help other users benefit from it.